# Stuck in power saving mode

Tags: power-management, 23.10

I'm on Ubuntu 23.10 I noticed that I cannot toggle out of **Power Saver mode**. When I choose either **Performance** or **Balanced**, it immediately switches back to Power Saver.

I've tried using `powerprofilesctl set balanced` to manually set it and it seems to work fine (no error messages), but it doesn't seem to change anything as `powerprofilesctl list` still says it's in the power-saver profile.

```
$ uname -r
6.5.0-14-generic
@thinkpad:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
R1FET55W (1.29 )
```

Lenovo ThinkPad L13 Gen 2
11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 × 8

Comment: What do the files with names suffixed with `_profile` in `/sys/firmware/acpi/` contain? Also what about `scaling_governor` and `scaling_available_governors` in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq`?

Comment: cat /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
low-power
powersave
performance powersave

these are

Comment: What are your `cat /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile_choices`? Does `echo performance | tee /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile` remain in that file 1. right after the command 2. after a reboot?

Comment: cat /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile_choices
low-power balanced performance
jason@thinkpad:~$ 
 every time it goes back to power saving mode I do not know how to check it which you are saying. I am litte bit new in the linux world

Comment: echo performance | tee /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile
tee: /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile: Permission denied
performance
jason@thinkpad:~$

Comment: Oops, please do `sudo tee` instead

Comment: sudo echo performance | tee /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile
tee: /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile: Permission denied
performance
jason@thinkpad:~$ sudo echo performance | tee /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile
anyway it shows permission denied

Comment: jason@thinkpad:~$ sudo echo performance | sudo tee /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile
performance
jason@thinkpad:~$ cat /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile_choices
low-power balanced performance
jason@thinkpad:~$

Comment: Ok, now `cat /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile`?

Comment: jason@thinkpad:~$ cat /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile
low-power

Comment: This means the problem is not in userspace. The setting is probably locked in BIOS. Check `sudo dmesg` to see if there are any interesting lines at the bottom. If you still believe the setting is not locked, please file a bug against the kernel on Launchpad.

Comment: do you have an email or zoom to check my laptop its because that last command shows bunch of stuff I do not know which to look at. I will message you if you do not mind, I will appreciate if you could fix it. I really disturbs me a lot

Comment: Just run `sudo dmesg | tail` to limit the amount of stuff it outputs. Do that immediately after the `echo | sudo`. On StackExchange sites, we use the Chat link at the bottom of the page instead of email or zoom, but you don't have enough reputation. I would recommend going through your BIOS settings thoroughly.

Comment: $ echo | sudo
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-ABkNnS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-ABkNnS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user]
            [-u user] [command [arg ...]]

Comment: usage: sudo [-ABbEHkNnPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-D directory]
            [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-R directory] [-T timeout]
            [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i | -s] [command [arg ...]]
usage: sudo -e [-ABkNnS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-D directory]
            [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-R directory] [-T timeout]
            [-u user] file ...

Comment: on@thinkpad:~$ sudo dmesg | tail
[sudo] password for jason: 
[   10.590237] Initialized host personality
[   10.602280] NET: Registered PF_VSOCK protocol family
[   10.736169] systemd-journald[275]: /var/log/journal/aca133c322f74b9fb8ed43ac4a0cf401/user-1000.journal: Monotonic clock jumped backwards relative to last journal entry, rotating.
[   10.827266] audit: type=1400 audit(1706524274.696:158): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/20671/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2078 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"

Comment: What I meant was the `echo performance | sudo tee /sys/firmware/acpi/platform_profile` thing

Comment: Ok, looking at your latest dmesg, it appears nothing interesting happened when we were going through these steps. Please just check BIOS or report a bug.

Comment: thank you very much. I appreciate your help and support this community